# Can I cover insulation in my attic roof with plastic or plywood?

Tags: insulation, roof, attic

You can see into my attic a bit there (looking from the outside of the house into the attic), and it's insulation between the rafters. It's a small storage area and I'm tired of getting the itchies and having to worry about bumping into the insulation when moving boxes around. Can I nail up some thin plywood or some plastic sheeting? I figure boxing the air in like that would help with the insulation as well.

I'm no so concerned with the portions down at the very bottom where the attic flooring meets the rafters, but the higher part (where you can crouch and work in) I'd like to stop getting insulation on me.

[image]

Comment: Ir staple up some builders wrap

Comment: Yeah, plastic sheeting at the least. I'm getting itchy just looking at that picture.

Comment: Housewrap would be much more durable (resistant to tears and fastener pulloff). It is more expensive and LOUD when you're working with it, though, plus a bit crinkly later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Either wood or plastic would be a good idea.  You are only going to be able to get narrow sheets of plywood through those holes, but just nail them up.  If you use plastic, secure it with staples.